# Does DoFn.Context.output() make a copy of the object?

Tags: google-cloud-dataflow

Does DoFn.Context.output() make a copy of the object?

Is it safe to reuse an object after calling output? For example would the following code output 10 records with the same timestamp or 10 records with different timestamps?

```
public void processElement(DoFn<LogMessage, Event>.ProcessContext c) throws Exception {
  Event e = new Event();
  for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    e.setTimestampMs(i);
    c.output(e);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, generally it is not safe to modify `elem` after a call to `c.output(elem)`.

This is because `elem` is passed to the consumer(s) without copying (for efficiency). The consumer may want to buffer its input elements (`c.element()`) before processing. Modifying output `elem` would affect the buffered elements.